# How does one set an Excel color theme to the default "Office" through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, colors, themes, default

I have a series of Excel workbooks that are currently set to color themes other than "Office" and I want to set them all back to the default "Office" color theme using VBA.

I know how to set the Excel color theme for a workbook in Excel to other themes using this command in VBA (ex: Office 2007 - 2010 theme):

**wkbk.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Document Themes 16\Theme Colors\Office 2007 - 2010.xml")**

but I'm unable to determine how to set the color theme to the default "Office" theme.    Comparing the color themes listed in the Excel ribbon and xml files under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Document Themes 16\Theme Colors", all are there in the folder except for "Office".

Using MS Office 365.

- Leaving it blank like **wkbk.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load ()** causes an error.
- Leaving it blank like **wkbk.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load ("")** does nothing.
- Setting it to "Office" like **wkbk.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load ("Office")** does nothing.

I'm hoping someone knows how.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how to load "Office" color theme directly, **but**

you could activate it and then save in a .xlm file using `ThemeColorScheme.Save` method [REF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.themecolorscheme.save), which could be loaded later.

#### Code

You could utilize the solution from [Vikas and akjoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807148/11820775):

```
Private Sub CopyTheme(baseBook As Workbook, targetBook As Workbook)
Dim themeName As String
themeName = Environ("temp") & "\VBANoobTheme.xml"

'save theme
On Error Resume Next
Kill themeName
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
'delete extra sheets
baseBook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Save themeName
targetBook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load themeName
End Sub
```

You could then loop through files and call the above script, by something like this:
**insert file paths in** `target_Wb_names`

```
Sub main()
Dim target_Wb_names   As Variant
Dim baseBook            As Workbook
Dim targetBook          As Workbook

'insert paths to files where you want to
'change the color theme
target_Wb_names = Array( _
                    [path1], _
                    [path2])

'select "Office" color theme in this workbook
Set baseBook = ThisWorkbook

'looping through files tp change Color themes
For Each name In target_Wb_names:
    Set targetBook = Workbooks.Open(name)
    'calling script from (Vikas and akjoshi)
    Call CopyTheme(baseBook, targetBook)
    targetBook.Save
Next name

End Sub
```

##### Remember to select the "Office" color theme in the "base book" before running the script.

Vote up, if the solution works for you :-)